# Use a control in MainWindow from a nested page WPF VB.NET

Tags: wpf, vb.net, visual-studio, xaml

I have a program in visual basic .net and WPF that uses a series of pages displayed in a `Frame` control on my main `Window`, pages are navigated from controls in the main `Window` outside of the frame and I have all that working ok.

I also have a `MediaElement` control on that main `Window` and I need to be able to change the source property of this control from the user clicking on elements in the pages. Every time I have tried to do this so far i have run into an error.

Right now I have a Public Shared function within main `Window` that is called from the control in the page, the code on the control passes on the URL to be loaded into the source property to the function, then the function is supposed to pass the url into the source property and tell the `MediaElement` to play.

The error I am getting when trying to achieve this is:

> Cannot refer to an instance member of a class from within a shared
>   method or shared member initializer without an explicit instance of
>   the class.

Please help, how could I achive this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you very much Steve for your answer, however I found how to do what I need on another post after idly trying some different search terms today.

Someone known as Jean on another post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16781963/2668533 suggested something that worked for me, by using application.current.windows:

```
Dim parent As MainWindow = Application.Current.Windows(0)
parent.player.Source = New Uri(url)
```

Apologies for seeming such a novice but WPF is completely new to me and I have never encounterd a need for anything similer using WindowsForms.

Answer (score 0):

Are you getting an instance of the main window or the media element inside of your shared function?  If not, this is you problem.

You might stick the media element into a shared variable when the main window is loaded or you can access your main window using the rootvisual of your application.current.app.rootvisual.

If your issue is something else, please post the code in your shared function that causes the error.