# Setting Text From Class other than Main

Tags: c#, wpf, textbox

I'm trying to change the text in a text box on WPF form. So far:

This is my method that updates the text box. It's in MainWindow.cs

```
public void BodyText(string message)
    {

        txtBody.Clear();
        txtBody = new TextBox();
        txtBody.Text = message;  
    }
```

And I'm trying to update the textbox from a different class by

```
MainWindow.BodyText(e.bodyresult);
```

where `e.bodyresult` is a string

I've read a lot of different things and none of them seem to work as I would expect. I'm reasonably new to C#, so any help would be appreciated

Comment: Normally, you'd just bind the `TextBox.Text` property to a data structure that has the text you want. But if you want to do it programmatically, the first step would be to not create a whole new `TextBox` object. Just set the `Text` property (i.e. remove the first two statements in your `BodyText()` method).

Comment: @PeterDuniho I've changed that now, but it won't let me call the method as it's not a static class? However, I can't use a static class as I would need to pass the textbox as a parameter

Comment: might be able to pass a delegate into the other class that will be used to call your BodyText method... I haven't written c# in a while but I used to use delegates a lot to update a UI while a process was running with them

Comment: @JordanMoffat: it's hard to offer advice with so little code in your question. But the rules are pretty simple: if you want to call a non-static member, you have to have an instance reference. If you have an instance of `MainWindow`, then there's _some_ code that knows about it. That code needs to tell the code that calls `BodyText()` about that. Alternatively, data binding or having the `MainWindow` class itself subscribe to an event on the class that gets the `e.bodyresult` value would work (and in fact are preferred, generally).

Comment: Probably a duplicate question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13644114/how-can-i-access-a-control-in-windows-wpf-from-another-class-or-windows

Answer (score 0):

`MainWindow` is the name of a class. In your other class you need to have access to the instance of that type that is acting as your main window.

Something like this:

```
        MainWindow  x = (MainWindow) App.Current.MainWindow;
        x.BodyText("Message");
```