# Access a variable on another page UWP

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

I have this Imagebox in my UserControl.Xaml

```
 <Image x:Name="MainImage" Margin="20,20,20,20" Source="{Binding FrontImage}" Stretch="Fill" Canvas.ZIndex="2" Width="391" Height="355">
```

Is there anyway to reach the

```
 x:Name="MainImage"
```

in my Mainpage.XAML.cs file?

i have tried this but that didn't seem to work

```
     public Image MainImage
        {
            get { return MainImage; }
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am pretty sure you want something like this:

[How can I access a control in WPF from another class or window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13644114/how-can-i-access-a-control-in-wpf-from-another-class-or-window)

**Basically you make the xaml property public, then you find the window instances of the application, find the one you want and then modify it.**

I cant add comments with my current points, so i leave the link as an answer here. Dont forget to upvote the actual author of the answer.

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is "you shouldn't".

The long answer is: like his predecessor named WPF, UWP framework intends MVVM approach. This means you should avoid placing much logic inside your views (aka "code behind" *.xaml.cs files). Instead, you should work with models and view-models, depending on your very goals.

For instance, at your case you should work with FrontImage (that could be in appropriate view-model) instead of trying to reach MainImage XAML control (that is in your view indeed). Then, you can reach given instance of the view-model via IoC framework you use (or its hand-written equivalent that to resolve such dependencies between view-models and models and to manage created instances in case they're multiple).