Access WPF element from inside a class
May somebody give me a hint why I cannot access a WPF element via its Name from inside a class (which is part of the MainWindow)? I don't get it why its not possible via name as it is for the Click function of a MainWindow Button.
Example & Problem: A StackPanel (StackPanel1) in a Scrollviewer accomodates ListBoxes. Two Buttons add ListBoxes in this StackPanel by using two different approaches. The first Button directly access the StackPanel1 and adds children, the second button uses a class (MyClass). I cannot access the StackPanel via its Name inside of this class as it is possible for the Click Function. Why?
xaml:
<Window x:Class="WpfApp.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Grid>
        <!-- Scrollviewer contain ListBoxes -->
        <ScrollViewer Margin="20,84,20,175" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden">
            <StackPanel Name="StackPanel1" Orientation="Horizontal" Height="150">
                <ListBox d:ItemsSource="{d:SampleData ItemCount=5}" Height="150" Width="120" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
                <ListBox d:ItemsSource="{d:SampleData ItemCount=5}" Height="150" Width="120" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
                <ListBox d:ItemsSource="{d:SampleData ItemCount=5}" Height="150" Width="120" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </ScrollViewer>
        <!-- Button for adding ListBoxes-->
        <Button Name="Add_Elements_Directly" Content="Add Listboxes directly" Margin="30,284,545,100" Click="Add_Elements_Directly_Click" />
        <Button Name="Add_Elements_ViaClass" Content="Add Listboxes via class" Margin="288,284,288,100" Click="Add_Elements_ViaClass_Click" />

    </Grid>
</Window>

cs:
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace WpfApp
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        class MyClass
        {
            public void AddNewListBoxes(StackPanel sp)
            {
                ListBox lb = new ListBox();
                lb.Width = 120;
                lb.Height = 150;
                lb.HorizontalAlignment = System.Windows.HorizontalAlignment.Left;
                sp.Children.Add(lb);
                // StackPanel1.Children.Add(lb);  // does not work! Why?
            }
        }


        private void Add_Elements_Directly_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            ListBox lb = new ListBox();
            lb.Width = 120;
            lb.Height = 150;
            lb.HorizontalAlignment = System.Windows.HorizontalAlignment.Left;
            StackPanel1.Children.Add(lb);
        }

        private void Add_Elements_ViaClass_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            MyClass myClass = new MyClass();
            StackPanel sp = StackPanel1;   // StackPanel1 from xaml
            myClass.AddNewListBoxes(sp);

        }
    }
}


This question is similar to: In WPF, what are the differences between the x:Name and Name attributes?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

The following may be of interest: x:Name Directive

In fact x:Name does not solve the problem. There is still no access in code behind for me. What solves the problem and gives access to the StackPanel control: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13644114/how-can-i-access-a-control-in-wpf-from-another-class-or-window.  I.e the code: System.Windows.Window window=System.Windows.Application.Current.MainWindow; (window as MainWindow).StackPanel1.Children.Add(lb); 

You should not use the as operator without checking the result for null. See the edited version of the answer that you have found.

It seems that I missed the comment in your post. The code that you posted works, as is. The content of your post doesn't seem to ask the question that you really have  which is why you can't use: StackPanel1.Children.Add(lb); inside of MyClass. Doing such a thing isn't allowed. However, as you discovered, one can pass the StackPanel as a parameter to the method.

It seems that you don't actually have an issue, but rather need to find some resources to learn/understand the basics of C#.

The following may be of interest: Introduction to classes and Methods (C# Programming Guide)

Thank you all. Yes, it seems that I need to dive more into classes. But actually I hoped that somebody here could give me a hint why it's not allowed. MyClass is part of the MainWindow class and StackPanel1is part of MainWindow as defined in xaml. That's why I expected a simple access. Regarding the as operator you are right, in fact I used a null check but didn't show it for brevity.
